# Generator sizing for water pump

Tags: motor, generator

I'm trying to size a backup generator for a water pump system.

The pump is rated 3HP / 230V / 13.5 A

So it seems that I would need a ~ 3KW generator on a steady state.

However, I'm aware of the need to design for inrush start current. The pump code is H, which from table gives about 6.7 mid range value.

Is the start power required then 3 * 6.7 = 20KW?

Seems that it would lead a grossly oversized the generator. Any guidance of what's acceptable?

Comment: No, 3kW * 3 is 9kW - this is motor inrush current.

Comment: Yeah, that's what happens with generators. Are you sure modern solutions like battery banks (Tesla PowerWall being a high-end option) can't help here?  Let the battery/inverter  worry about the surge, at that point you can make up the gap with a much smaller generator or even some solar panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6.7 multiplier applied to the rated motor current results in 6.7 x 13.5 = 90.5 amps. The current is the most important thing to consider. Since the current at starting lags the voltage by quite a bit, the starting kW will be a lot less than the starting kVA. 90.5 x 230 = 20.8 kVA. You should look for a generator that has a published motor-starting or surge rating published. You should also determine if the generator has a main circuit breaker or other protection that will disconnect the load if the current is too high.

When the motor starts, you can expect the current to pull down the output voltage considerably, perhaps 30 percent. That will be good for the starting situation, because it will reduce the starting current, perhaps by 50%. That voltage reduction will reduce the starting torque. If the load is a centrifugal pump, that should not be a problem. Centrifugal pumps require very little torque to start. If it is a piston pump, you will have a problem.

If the motor is started by a motor contactor with a coil that is connected to the generator output, that contactor may drop out or chatter. You might want to consider a manual motor starting switch.

You should try to borrow or rent a generator that has a surge current or motor starting rating of 50 amps or 10 to 12 kVA. Try that. If it works buy it or one like it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to not need such a huge generator, you could try a soft starter. You can make one with a $5 10 ohm thermistor, or buy a $50 one rated for 15 amps from china. There is not much information out there. I ended up just using a plastic electrical box to contain 4 x 2.5 ohm thermistors in series and a fan to cool them off at run time.